# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in

Tags: php

```
$sql = SELECT " .$fields. "
    FROM incident_reports as incident_reports
    LEFT JOIN manage_outcome_otc  ON outcome = id_otc
    LEFT JOIN venues_area_vna ON venue_area = id_vna
    LEFT JOIN user_categories_uct as usrcatname ON usrcatname.id_uct = usrcat.cat_id
    LEFT JOIN zone ON pk_zone = zone_vns
    LEFT JOIN regions_rgs ON id_rgs = region_vns
    WHERE 1=1 {$dateFilter} 
    GROUP BY incident_reports.inc_id  ". $limit ;


 $resultSql = $mx_shop_pdo->prepare($sql); 

 $resultSql->execute();
```

I am not very much familiar with PDO . The above code gives me Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in Line 70.

```
line 70 :  $resultSql->execute();
```

Can anyone help me out ?

```
$fields = "incident_reports.inc_id ,
ir_reference , ist.name_it as statusName, created_time, assigned_to as created_by, vs.name,
CONCAT( TRIM(usr.firstname_usr),' ',TRIM(usr.lastname_usr) ) as reported_by, usrlvl.level_ulv,
GROUP_CONCAT(usrcatname.title_uct) AS title";

$dateFilter = "AND DATE(`date`) BETWEEN '01/01/2011' AND '15/04/2020' ";

$limit = '';
```

Comment: What's in all of these variables that you use in this code?

Comment: those have got values assigned to it

Comment: That's obvious, but we can't see your code, so we are unable to help without knowing the contents of those.

Comment: Can you `echo $dateFilter;` to see what that has?

Comment: $fields = "incident_reports.inc_id ,
ir_reference , ist.name_it as statusName"

Comment: $dateFilter = "AND DATE(`date`) BETWEEN '01/01/2011' AND '15/04/2020' "

Comment: dont see any declaration of `ist` and `usrcat` and `usr`  in your query.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax highlighting should tell you you have a problem. Look at your `"`. Here's what the `$sql` should look like:

```
$sql = " SELECT " .$fields. "
    FROM incident_reports as incident_reports
    LEFT JOIN manage_outcome_otc  ON outcome = id_otc
    LEFT JOIN venues_area_vna ON venue_area = id_vna
    LEFT JOIN user_categories_uct as usrcatname ON usrcatname.id_uct = usrcat.cat_id
    LEFT JOIN zone ON pk_zone = zone_vns
    LEFT JOIN regions_rgs ON id_rgs = region_vns
    WHERE 1=1 {$dateFilter} 
    GROUP BY incident_reports.inc_id  ". $limit ;


 $resultSql = $mx_shop_pdo->prepare($sql); 

 $resultSql->execute();
```